# JavaScript Countdown Timer limitation?

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I want to make a website with a countdown. I've tried using JavaScript method using new Date() function as instructed on w3school https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp. However, the timer varies from devices. It keeps changing depending on time of the user's device. What's the common way of doing this to make the countdown same for everyone?

Thank you.

Comment: Count down how many minutes?

Comment: the time is relative and will be related to where is the user located, those are called time zones

Comment: Set the Date Instead of writing just new Date()

Answer (score 1):

Try using Date.now() instead of new Date(), or take a look to this [Mozilla's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).